# Texts are not moving from first page to second page

Tags: altacv

[image: Overleaf output ( Latex )]

I'm stuck at this part. The left column's texts are automatically moving from upper page to lower page. But the right column's texts are not moving down from upper to lower page. In other word, the texts of the right column's, after reaching the border between upper and lower page, instead of moving to the lower page, it remains in the same page. A little bit texts are appearing in the border, marked by a rectangular red box.

I want the right column's texts moved to the lower page like the left column's texts. Can anyone please help?

**updated part**: [source code](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kdqrjndrqqyn)

Comment: There are many different ways to create two column documents (\twocolumn, multicol, paracol plus certain document classes).  Please provide a Minimal Working Example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have edited the question. Please have a glimpse at the updated part

Comment: please don't use external links, your question is arrchived here forever and will not be understandable if the code at teh link changes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have no idea what else way I can use. Can you please suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make to start a new page before a `\cvsection` to have good titles alignment and also "call" the `page2sidebar`

```
\clearpage
\cvsection[page2sidebar]{Education}
```

[image: a]

This is the main code: (geometry setup changed)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv}

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1cm,right=11cm,marginparwidth=8cm,marginparsep=1.5cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.50cm} % changed<<<<<<<<<<<

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Carlito}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{VividPurple}{HTML}{3E0097}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{37474F}
\colorlet{heading}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{accent}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\name{Kazi Ziaul Hassan}
\tagline{Problem Solver, Competitive Programmer}

% Cropped to square from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marissa_Mayer#/media/File:Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_(cropped).jpg, CC-BY 2.0
\photo{2.5cm}{American-passport-photo}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
    \email{Computer Science and Engineering, BSc-CSE(KUET)}
    
    \location{Khulna}
    
    
%   \orcid{orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000} % Obviously making this up too. If you want to use this field (and also other academicons symbols), add "academicons" option to \documentclass{altacv}
}



%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want.
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

%% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}    

\cvsection[page1sidebar]{Basic info}
\printinfo{Contact}{+8801679388394}
\printinfo{Email}{kazi.kuet@gmail.com}   
\printinfo{Linkedin}{\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/kazi-ziaul-hassan/}{Kazi Ziaul Hassan.}}
\printinfo{StackOverflow}{\href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/9258528/kazi-ziaul-hassan}{Kazi Ziaul Hassan}}
\printinfo{Stopstalk}{\href{https://www.stopstalk.com/user/profile/Crackeree}{Kazi Ziaul Hassan}}
\printinfo{Codeforces}{\href{https://codeforces.com/profile/Kazi_Ziaul_Hassan}{Kazi Ziaul Hassan}}
\printinfo{Codechef}{\href{https://www.codechef.com/users/crackeree_61}{crackeree\_61. . . .}}
\printinfo{Lightoj}{\href{https://lightoj.com/user/kazi-kuet}{Kazi Ziaul Hassan}}
\printinfo{Uhunt}{\href{https://uhunt.onlinejudge.org/id/904351}{Kazi Ziaul Hassan. . .}}
\printinfo{Hackerrank}{\href{https://www.hackerrank.com/kazi_kuet?hr_r=1}{Crackeree CRAK}}
\printinfo{Virtual Judge}{\href{https://vjudge.net/user/1607061}{1607061. . . . .}}
\printinfo{Spoj}{\href{https://www.spoj.com/status/crackeree/}{crackeree. . . . . . . . . .}}
\printinfo{Hackerearth}{\href{https://www.hackerearth.com/@kazi15}{Kazi Ziaul Hassan}}  

\printinfo{Timus}{\href{https://acm.timus.ru/author.aspx?id=246535}{Zia}}

\printinfo{Date of Birth}{28th January, 1998}

\printinfo{Blood Group}{O+ve}

\printinfo{Address}{Holding No: 71,

Middle Arichpur, Tongi, Gazipur}

\vspace{10px}

\cvsection{About me}
\begin{itemize}
\item I am a final year student of Computer Science and Engineering department in KUET. I am adept in competitive programming and problem solving. Highly ambitious, hard-working, team player, leader, adamant, very optimistic, enthusiastic, responsible and punctual. I love to learn new things and do challenging tasks. I also love mathematics, coding, traveling, bike riding, tasting delicious food and Cricket. I believe, "The more you mistake, the more you know. The more you know, 
the less you fear".
\end{itemize}

\vspace{10px}

\cvsection{Work Experience}

\cvevent{Former math and chemistry teacher}{Udvash}{Aug 2017 -- November 2019}{Khulna}
\vspace{10px}

\cvevent{Text and image annotator}{Next-Solution Lab}{Nov 2020 -- Dec 2020}{Dhaka}
\vspace{10px}


\cvevent{Audio annotator team leader}{Intel't Machines}{Jan 2021 -- Mar 2021}{Dhaka}
\vspace{10px}

%\cvevent{Aircraft Maintenance Engineering Internship }{Air %Algerie}{sep 2017 -- Jan 2018}{Algeria, Algiers}
%\begin{itemize}
 %   \item Establishment of a Peer-to-peer ATC communication %simulation.
   % \item Troubleshooting and maintnance of a weather Radar .
%\end{itemize}

\clearpage
\cvsection[page2sidebar]{Education}

\cvevent{B.Sc in Computer Science and Engineering}{
Khulna University of Engineering and Technology
}
{Jan 2017 -- Ongoing}{Khulna}
{\faMortarBoard CGPA: 3.37/4.00 (upto 6th semester)}

\vspace{10px}
\cvevent{Higher Secondary Certificate}{Gpvt Science College \hfill \faMortarBoard GPA: 5.00/5.00}{Jan 2014 -- Dec 2016}{Dhaka}
\vspace{10px}
\cvevent{Secondary School Certificate}{Siraj Uddin Sarker Vidyaniketan \& College \hfill \faMortarBoard GPA: 5.00/5.00  }{Jan 2011 -- Dec 2013}{Gazipur}
{\faMortarBoard Got General Grade Stipend}

\end{document
```

This is **page1sidebar.tex**

```
\cvsection{Achievements}

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Best Team Award, 2019}{My team participated in Intra KUET Programming contest. We achieved the "Best Team Award" from our batch.}
\cvtag{Onsite Contest} 
\cvtag{Teamwork}
\cvtag{Decision Making}
\cvtag{Problem Solving}
\cvtag{Algorithm}
\cvtag{Data Structure}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Champion, IKMO, 2017}{I participated in Intra KUET Mathematics Olympiad  (IKMO). I became the champian.}
\cvtag{Advanced Mathematics} 
\cvtag{Decision Making}
\cvtag{Problem Solving} 

\divider

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{StackOverflow \~260 Reputation, Gold Badge}{I gave solutions to many users who had been facing problems regarding programming languages or other technical issues. I used to post my problems as well. }
\cvtag{Debugging} 
\cvtag{Proficiency}
\cvtag{Problem Solving} 

\divider

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Codechef 3 Star Rating}{Codechef is a online progranning contest platform. I achieved 3 star rating.}
\cvtag{Online Contest} 
\cvtag{Martinet}
\cvtag{Decision Making}
\cvtag{Problem Solving}
\cvtag{Algorithm}
\cvtag{Data Structure}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faUsers}{National Collegiate Programming Contest (NCPC)}
{

Rank: 282 in 2018
\divider
Rank: 152 in 2019

}
\cvtag{Online Contest} 
\cvtag{Martinet}
\cvtag{Decision Making}
\cvtag{Problem Solving}
\cvtag{Algorithm}
\cvtag{Data Structure}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faUsers}{National Undergraduate Mathematics Olympiad}
{

9th Undergrad Regional Math Olympiad, Khulna, 2017
\divider
Status: Certified

10th Undergrad Regional Math Olympiad, Khulna, 2018
\divider
Status: Certified

}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faUsers}{Around 1000 Problems Solved}
{
I have solved around thousand problems of various categories and difficulties in Codeforces, UVA, Hackerrank, Codechef, Lightoj, SPOJ, Timus, ACMSGURU etc.
}
```

This is **page2sidebar.tex**

```
\cvsection{Skills}

\textcolor{SlateGrey}{\textbf{Internet Of Things}}
\newline

\begin{itemize}
    \item MQTT Protocol, MQTT broker setup, Mesh Network Design.
    \item AWS IoT and Microsoft Azure IoT setup.
\end{itemize}

\textcolor{SlateGrey}{\textbf{Hardware}}
\newline

\begin{itemize}
    \item ESP programming using ESP-IDF, Xtensy-based mcu, ARM-based mcu (STM32x, Cortex ...)
    \item  Data Logger Design, Programmable Logic Controller design, VHDL, Power electronics.
\end{itemize}   

\textcolor{SlateGrey}{\textbf{Robotics}}
\newline

\begin{itemize}
    \item Closed Loop Control, SLAM robotics
    \item Accelerometer based system (Kallman Filters, quaternion based algorithms).
\end{itemize}

\textcolor{SlateGrey}{\textbf{Software (Backend)}}
\newline

\begin{itemize}
    \item AWS server/CPanel setup (web hosting, Cloud hosting, Restful API, Redis, SQL ..).
    \item Linux Kernel API, POSIX, V system, Clustering, Multi-threading, FreeRTOS.
\end{itemize}

\textcolor{SlateGrey}{\textbf{Software (Frontend)}}
\newline

\begin{itemize}
    \item Multi-platform Apps (Cordova, PhonegapBuild, Ionic, QT).
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Languages}

English \hfill TOEIC (975) 

\divider

French \hfill C2 

\divider

Arabic \hfill Native 

\cvsection{Other Interests}

\cvtag{Basketball}
\cvtag{Philosophy}
\cvtag{Astronomy}
\cvtag{Quantum Mechanics}
\cvtag{Classical Music}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

If you use the newer files provided [here](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV) or [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-template/trgqjpwnmtgv), the sample files now use `\begin{paracol}{2}...\end{paracol}` instead of passing `page2sidebar.tex` to `\cvsection` as an optional argument. The `paracol` environment supports automatic page breaking in both columns.